# Type I error in Normal distributions

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Let $X_1,\dots , X_n \stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(\mu, \sigma^2 = 4)$ Test $H_0: \mu = 10$ vs $H_1: \mu > 10$ take a random sample of $n=16$ and reject $H_0$ if $\bar{x}>14$

Find $\alpha$ the type I error probability

Im using $\bar{x} \stackrel{H_0}{\sim} N(10,\frac{4}{16})$

Test statistic formula is

$Z=\frac{\bar{X-\mu}}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}\stackrel{H_0}{\sim} N(0,1)$

Using $\alpha= P(\bar{X}>14)= P(Z> \frac{14-10}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{16}}})$ to reject $H_0$ I get $P(Z >8)$

I plugged it in R as $1-P(Z \leq8)$ which gives a value of $6.6612^{-16}$ which is ridiculously small. Am I doing this correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes that is right, the type I error is really small. On the other hand, the type II error should be bad with this critical region.

Comment: @Augustin, to elaborate on that, if for example $\mu = 11$ to find $\beta$ the type II error, do I use the same approach. I tried the same and  got a value of $2.8665^{-07}$ which still very small. what am I missing? Thanks

Comment: You should find something close to 1. Are you sure you used the right definition for $\beta$ ?

Comment: @Augustin is not $\beta=P(\bar{x}>14)$? can't be since that is the calculation for $\alpha$ I'm not quiet sure.

Comment: No, type II error is when you do not reject the null hypothesis whereas you should reject it.
In this particular case, for $\mu =11$ the type II error is $P(\bar{X}\leq 14\vert \mu=11)$.

Comment: I see, when I do the calculation I get $P(Z \leq 6)$ which in R as pnorm(6) is equal to 1. can I calculated using  $\beta - power$

Comment: Yes the answer is $P(Z\leq 6)$. R prints $1$ but it's actually only very close to $1$. This shows that the power of the test is terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you've done it correctly. However, there is some inaccuracy in your answer due to the floating-point roundoff error which happens because you are subtracting $P(Z \leq 8)$, which is close to 1, from 1:

```
> 1-pnorm(8)
[1] 6.661338e-16
```

Instead of this, a better method is to use the option `lower.tail=FALSE' to give the upper tail directly:

```
pnorm(8,lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 6.220961e-16
```

or equivalently, using the symmetry of the standard normal distribution,

```
> pnorm(-8)
[1] 6.220961e-16
```

Comment: Got cha, thank you for clarifying.